# Creating a Haskell function using foldl to turn a list of ints to a single int

Tags: haskell

I have to define a function, prob2, that takes a list of Ints and returns an Int using foldl:

```
HW3*> prob2 [2,3,4,5]

2345
```

I lack experience using folds.  What I have is this:

```
prob2 :: [Integer] -> Integer

prob2 (x:xs) = foldl (\x->10*x+xs) 0
```

Comment: Alternately, `prob2 = foldl (+) 0 . map (+ 10)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are still thinking in terms of recursion. You seem to think of the problem as applying the function to the head of the element and the tail.
But `foldl` takes a binary operator and applies it to elements of the list in a cumulative fashion. It requires a binary operator for items of the same type.

You need a lambda expression with 2 parameters, like this:

```
foldl (\x y -> 10*x+y) 0  [2,3,4,5]
```

This will yield your integer 2345.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a way of looking at this symbolically that I like to use. Instead of `foldl`, let's take a look at `foldl1` first for simplicity. Note, that using `foldl1` is often not a good idea since it is a partial function (passing an empty list results in an exception).

You can imagine `foldl1` takes an operator and a list and replaces the commas in the list with this operator (along with appropriately placed parentheses, of course), e.g.

```
foldl1 (+) [1, 2, 3, 4] =
(((1 + 2) + 3) + 4)     =
((3 + 3) + 4)           =
(6 + 4)                 =
10
```

If associativity holds for the operator, you can naturally omit the parentheses altogether. From this, it is obvious that the operator/function you pass to `foldl` is always operating on two single elements at the time.

Note that the `foldl` function is more general since the type of the initial/resulting value doesn't have to be the same as the type of the list's elements, but the above visualization still applies if you imagine the initial value as "standing" in front of the list:

```
(+>) :: Show a => String -> a -> String
(+>) accumulator x = accumulator ++ show x

foldl (+>) "" [1, 2, 3, 4]     =
(((("" +> 1) +> 2) +> 3) +> 4) =
((("1" +> 2) +> 3) +> 4)       =
(("12" +> 3) +> 4)             =
("123" +> 4)                   =
"1234"
```

Comment: +1 for "replacing the commas in the list with this operator". BTW the question states that the end result should be an Integer, not a String.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I know, but I thought that your answer already takes care of answering OP's concrete question, so I meant that latter example as a way of demonstrating that the types of the accumulator and the elements of the list don't have to be the same.

Comment: Seems a useful addition indeed.